# H2 issue with left outer join

Tags: h2

I have a query and not sure why H2 has a issue with the query (working on Oracle and MS SQL). The issue is the left outer join.

```
    select "FOO"."ID"
    from "FOO" where ("FOO"."ID" in (
      select distinct "FOO"."ID" from "FOO", "OTHER_TABLE"
      left outer join "BAR" "t1" on "FOO"."ID" = "t1"."FOO_ID"  ))
```

Error:
Column "FOO"."ID" not found; SQL statement:

Also tried to alias the left outer join also not working

```
    select "FOO"."ID"
    from "FOO", "OTHER_TABLE" where ("FOO"."ID" in (
      select distinct t2."ID" from "FOO", "OTHER_TABLE" t2
      left outer join "BAR" "t1" on t2."ID" = "t1"."FOO_ID"  ))
```

Anyone have an idea how I can solve this?

EDIT: Found out the "OTHER_TABLE" in the from makes a problem

Comment: Both queries with sample schema `CREATE TABLE FOO(ID INT) AS VALUES 1, 2, 3; CREATE TABLE OTHER_TABLE(ID INT) AS VALUES 1, 2; CREATE TABLE BAR(ID INT, FOO_ID INT) AS VALUES (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 2);` return the expected result without any errors in the latest H2 2.1.214.

Comment: Sorry added the "OTHER_TABLE"  into the wrong select. Could you try it again?
Tried it with H2 2.1.214

Comment: Table reference `"OTHER_TABLE" left outer join "BAR" "t1" on "FOO"."ID" = "t1"."FOO_ID"` doesn't have table `"FOO"` used in its join condition, this table only exists in another table reference in the `FROM` clause, maybe you meant `("FOO" JOIN "OTHER_TABLE") left outer join "BAR" "t1" on "FOO"."ID" = "t1"."FOO_ID"` or something like it?

Comment: If you do something like this. Wondering that other sql provider support this. 
  select "FOO"."ID"
    from "FOO" where ("FOO"."ID" in (
      select distinct "FOO"."ID" from "FOO","OTHER_TABLE" 
      left outer join "BAR" "t1" on "FOO"."ID" = "t1"."FOO_ID"  
      where "OTHER_TABLE".name = 'MyName'))